# clearTimeout not working on mouseup event

Tags: javascript, settimeout, mousemove, mouseup, cleartimeout

Why is timeout not being cleared in this setup? How can I make up() stop the delayed actions from running?

```
var active = false;
var delay;

window.addEventListener("mousedown", down, false);
window.addEventListener("mouseup", up, false);
window.addEventListener("mousemove", move, false);

function down(e) {
    active = true;
    console.log("down")
    window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
}

function up(e) {
    active = false;
    clearTimeout(delay); //expecting this to clear delay
    console.log("up")
    window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
}

function move(e) {
    if (active) {
        delay = setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("move")
            window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
        }, 50);
    }
}
```

Expecting delay to be cleared on mouseup but it still executes.

Comment: You've only got a 50 millisecond delay.

Comment: You have one var for the timer: `delay`, but on mousemove a _whole bunch_ of MouseEvents get fired, each one overwriting the value of delay, so at best you can only clear _one_ of the many timeouts that will have been set.

Comment: @Pointy is right. `setTimeout` uses milliseconds, not seconds. Clicking in under 50 milliseconds is a bit hard if that's what you intended...

Comment: every movemeet you are making another timer. The timer is active, and you make a new one, and another, and another..... and you only can cancel the last one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've learned from the replies that `setTimeout` produces a new independent timer every time `move()` is executed. My understanding was that each new timer overwrites the previous one but as this is not the case I had to think of something else.

I did't really explain what I actually needed to achieve with the delay so let me clarify. I want to create a timeout for an action if that action has not been executed for x amount of time. Using setTimeout on the action it self created the problem that the action would still potentially have multiple queued executions waiting to happen even after mouseup events.

So instead I used setTimeout on a new variable that acts as a lock to the action. The result is the following code:

```
var active = false;
var actionTimeout = false;
var actionTimeStamp;
var actionLock = false;

window.addEventListener("mousedown", down, false);
window.addEventListener("mouseup", up, false);
window.addEventListener("mousemove", move, false);

function down(e) {
    active = true;
    console.log("down")
    window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
}

function up(e) {
    active = false;
    console.log("up")
    window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
}

function move(e) {
    if (active) {
        if ((Date.now() - actionTimeStamp > 500) && (!actionTimeout)) { // get time elapsed and compare to threshold (500ms)
            actionTimeout = true; //this is for the if statement above to prevent multiple timeouts
            actionLock = false; // set the lock
            setTimeout(function() { // remove lock after 50ms
                actionTimeout = false;
                actionLock = true;
                actionTimeStamp = Date.now(); // timestamp here to make sure we don't lock again to soon. (helps if setTimeout is => than threshold.
            }, 50);
        }
        if (actionLock) { //do our action
            console.log("move")
            window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
            actionTimeStamp = Date.now();  // timestamp last execution
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to everyone for chipping in with comments and answers. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You keep making timeouts on every movement. It does not replace the last one...

Your code is basically this

```
delay = setTimeout(function() { } <-- will run
delay = setTimeout(function() { } <-- will run
delay = setTimeout(function() { } <-- will run
delay = setTimeout(function() { } <-- will run
delay = setTimeout(function() { } <-- will run
delay = setTimeout(function() { } <-- will run
delay = setTimeout(function() { } <-- cancels this one
window.clearTimeout(delay)
```

So you need to remove it before you create a new one

```
if (active) {
    if (delay) window.clearTimeout(delay)
    delay = setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("move")
        window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
    }, 50);
}
```

If you need to move to fire more than once, that you want to look into throttling scripts.

Comment: throttling or debouncing

Comment: Hi! I don't believe this will work, unfortunately. When you clear a Timer the variable doesn't change, and it's always a positive integer. So delay would never not be true while "moving". This means the Timer's function will only fire if you drag and stay in a single place long enough that the Timer doesn't get cleared. Might be easier to check it out here: https://codepen.io/zfrisch/pen/PooNjLP?editors=1011

Comment: @zfrisch that doesn't matter what `delay` holds, they are checking for `active` state. The `if(delay)` is only there to avoid calling clearTimeout before it was assigned, which is completely useless because clearTimeout(undefined) is a noop, but still it's not a problem per se to have it.

Comment: @Kaiido it does matter. Did you try the demo?

Comment: @zfrisch The code in this answer will simply cancel any still active timeout before assigning a new one. `delay` should stay truthy for this code to work correctly. And your codepen exposes exactly the behavior this answer said it should expose: "move" is being logged only after a mousemove event when you keep pressing the button without moving for 50ms.

Comment: I can not use this. The code within delay var has to keep executing on and on as long as there are mousemove events between mousedown and mouseup.

Comment: This answer explained why your timeouts were firing. Ind the end, timeouts are the wrong thing. So that is what I said, use throttle or debounce to keep it firing. https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Comment: @Kaiido I think the issue here is that there's a misunderstanding what OP was asking. My impression was that they wanted their delayed function to continuously run every time the mouse moved while pressed, and only to stop when "mouseup" occurred - not to only fire once when the mouse stops moving but is still pressed.

Answer (score -1):

### Answer:

There are a few things to adjust in your code:

- Instead of continuously reassigning `delay` with a new `Timeout` Timer, simply use an `Interval`.
- You should only set the Timer if the state is active **AND** delay does not exist already. *this stops multiple Timers from existing*

There are a few things to adjust and understand about Timers in JavaScript:

- When you set a Timer, the variable that houses the Timer is set to return an Integer. This is the ID of the Timer in the current scope.
- When you clear a Timer, the variable isn't reset to `undefined` - it stays the same Integer/ID. This is because you're not *clearing* the variable, the scope is stopping the *Timer* that matches the ID the variable houses.
- Because of the above you have to explicitly set the variable housing the Timer to `undefined` (or some other `falsy` value) *after* clearing it for an existence check to work.

```js
var active = false;
var delay;

window.addEventListener("mousedown", down, false);
window.addEventListener("mouseup", up, false);
window.addEventListener("mousemove", move, false);

function down(e) {
    active = true;
    console.log("down")
    window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
}

function up(e) {
    active = false;
    clearTimeout(delay); //expecting this to clear delay
    delay = undefined;
    console.log("up")
    window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
}

function move(e) {
    if (active) {
      if(!delay) {
        delay = setInterval(function() {
            console.log("move")
            window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
        }, 50);
      }
    }
  else { //fallback in case of Browser Queuing issues
   if(delay) { 
     clearTimeout(delay);
     delay = undefined;
   }
  }
}
```

**Edited**

Due to comments with issues I added a fallback in **mousemove** that will remove the timer if the state is inactive, but `delay` is still defined. I don't believe that you technically should need this, but in practice Browser Event Queuing and Timers occasionally don't get along as expected.

Comment: I have tested this code and it works. However, about one out of ten times the "move" message keeps getting printed infinitely even though I released the mouse button and completely stopped moving the mouse.

Comment: @bewww I'm not able to reproduce that issue after attempting dozens of times here:  https://codepen.io/zfrisch/pen/NWWNgYN?editors=1011 . I'm not saying you're wrong, but firstly are you sure that you copied the entire snippet over? Specifically the portion where `delay` is set to `undefined` is very important. Secondly, if you have, can you tell me how you dragged/clicked in order to get the infinite "move" so I can try to reproduce it? Thanks!

Comment: I just click drag and release over and over again. It seems that the snippet here is less likely to get stuck, more like one in fifty times. It is much more likely to happen on jsfiddle. Also, try to make circular motions while clicking the mouse, this seems to increase the possibility.

Comment: @bewww I added a fallback. I'm really not able to reproduce it, so please let me know how it goes - but I think what you're experiencing is likely an issue with how different Browser Event Queues and Timers interact, which is a bit fickle. I edited the answer, but you can also view it here https://codepen.io/zfrisch/pen/dyyMVoO?editors=1111

Comment: The problem is still there. I am using Chrome, Win 10.

Comment: @bewww can you clarify what it is you were looking for? I've literally tried this in multiple browsers including the one that you're reporting on. What happens is that the delay function continuously runs until mouseup clears the timer. For me, under no circumstance that I've tried has the delayed function run once "mouseup" has fired. I'm thinking I may be misunderstanding what you're asking for.